# Understanding prototyping and oops implementation in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
var Todo = function(x){
 this.data = x;
    this.view = function(){
        alert("hi")
        check()
    }
    check = function(){
        alert("checking")
        alert(this.data)
    }
}
Todo.prototype.add = function(item){
    this.data.push(item)
}
var todo = new Todo([1,2,3])
alert(todo.data)
todo.add(5)
alert(todo.data)
todo.view()
```

In above code why I am not able to get the value of data in check method. I am little confused.

Comment: Maybe the following answer will be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941 As correctly answered the function check is a member of window (window.check) so when calling `window.check` then the invoking object is `window`. Invoking object is what `this` represent in the function body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have declared `check` as a global variable:

```
var a = 5; local variable
a = 5; global variable (attached to window)
```

therefore, the function context(`this`) is bound to `Window` when calling `check()`, which does not contain `data` property.

so you have to attach `check` function to Todo "class":

```
this.check = function() {};
```

a side note, you could get the desired functionality by setting manually the function context to `todo` when invoking the function:

```
check.apply(todo);
```

Answer (score 3):

`this` in the `check` function refers to the global object `window`.

Fix it with:

```
var Todo = function(x){
    this.data = x;
    this.view = function(){
        alert("hi");
        this.check();
    };
    this.check = function(){
        alert("checking");
        alert(this.data);
    };
};
```

And if you don't want to expose `check` method public, then you could do like below.

```
var Todo = function(x){
    this.data = x;
    this.view = function(){
        alert("hi")
        check.apply(this); //here, by using apply method
    }
    var check = function(){
        alert("checking")
        alert(this.data)
    }
}
```

Comment: yes that i know, i have tried that in jsfiddle, but I want to know why in check method this is not accessible? and if i check this in check method it gives me window object.

Comment: @jbmyid  the value of `this` is determined by how a function is called.